# How to programmatically log in to a website to screenscape?

Tags: c#, forms, authentication, web-scraping

I need some information from a website that's not mine, in order to get this information I need to login to the website to gather the information, this happens through a HTML form. How can I do this authenticated screenscaping in C#?

Extra information:

- Cookie based authentication.
- POST action needed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'd make the request as though you'd just filled out the form. Assuming it's POST for example, you make a POST request with the correct data. Now if you can't login directly to the same page you want to scrape, you will have to track whatever cookies are set after your login request, and include them in your scraping request to allow you to stay logged in.

It might look like:

```
HttpWebRequest http = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
http.KeepAlive = true;
http.Method = "POST";
http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string postData="FormNameForUserId=" + strUserId + "&FormNameForPassword=" + strPassword;
byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
// Probably want to inspect the http.Headers here first
http = WebRequest.Create(url2) as HttpWebRequest;
http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
http.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Maybe.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like something I could use, I'll accept this answer if it works when I get back to programming. :-)

Comment: This works if the web page is in plain HTML, but if the form is dynamically generated via Javascript.... would this work?

Comment: @Souper probably not; you would want to hand inspect what the requests going from sign-in to the page you want to scrape would be and then build up requests that mimic that behavior.

Comment: I used this as start, but had some problems along a way and adding other headers that were present in post made via webpage solved issue. If you have any problems you can help yourself with Poster extension for FF and wireshark to check what is send back and forth betwean computer and server.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. Just feed it the URL of the site, then use the DOM to set the username and password into the right fields, and eventually send a click to the submit button. This way you don't care about anything but the two input fields and the submit button. No cookie handling, no raw HTML parsing, no HTTP sniffing - all that is done by the browser control.

If you go that way, a few more suggestions:

1. You can prevent the control from loading add-ins such as Flash - could save you some time.
2. Once you login, you can obtain whatever information you need from the DOM - no need to parse raw HTML.
3. If you want to make the tool even more portable in case the site changes in the future, you can replace your explicit DOM manipulation with an injection of JavaScript. The JS can be obtained from an external resource, and once called it can do the fields population and the submit.

Comment: The problem is that I can't create a GUI form in this part of the application.

Comment: Well, that's too bad. if you get tired from doing the low-level stuff, you can try writing a separate GUI app that will be spawned from your app, do the scraping and communicate back the results. But that's kind of a stretch...

Comment: @eran +1. Your solution looks more complete.

Comment: Yea that works well in Forms and is relevant answer just to say that wont work in a pure web application though.

Answer (score 3):

For some cases, `httpResponse.Cookies` will be blank. Use the `CookieContainer` instead.

```
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest http = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
http.KeepAlive = true;
http.Method = "POST";
http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

http.CookieContainer = cc;

string postData="FormNameForUserId=" + strUserId + "&FormNameForPassword=" + strPassword;
byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
// Probably want to inspect the http.Headers here first
http = WebRequest.Create(url2) as HttpWebRequest;

http.CookieContainer = cc;

HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to dlambin answer
It is necessary to have

```
http.AllowAutoRedirect=false;
```

Otherwise

```
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

It will make another request to initial url and you won't be able to retrieve url2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the HTTPWebRequest and do a POST. This link should help you get started. The key is, you need to look at the HTML Form of the page you're trying to post from to see all the parameters the form needs in order to submit the post.

[http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20181030035238/http://www.netomatix.com:80/HttpPostData.aspx)

[http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123193021/http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx)

Comment: Yup, the hardest part I forgot to mention (because it's used most of the times) is to keep the cookie with me for the next page.