# Sign in to Email account from Desktop application

Tags: c#, javascript, google-chrome, gmail, mozilla

I have created one desktop form application in C#.net using visual studio 2008 and framework 4.0. I have one requirement like this: I have one link on one form and when user click on it, it will open up mozilla or chrome with gmail.com and username and password will be passed onclick event and gmail account will be opened up. so is it possible by anyway using C#.net or Javascript or JQuery or anything else?

Actually I dont want to embed any browser control with my window application instead opening a new instance of browser (mostly Firefox Or Chrome) it self with web site url, pass username and password and click on button to sing in.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the browser component (IE) inside your form itself than launching a seperate browser process. But i doubt if can pass the web page input programatically to a browser.

Plus see if this link could give you some fair idea [How to programmatically log in to a website to screenscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975426/how-to-programmatically-log-in-to-a-website-to-screenscape)

Comment: Actually I dont want to embed any browser control with my window application instead opening a new instance of browser it self with web site url, pass username and password and click on button to sing in.

Comment: You have to note one thing here, the web page isnt accepting any input, its the html page which is making the web page take the input. Its the web page which is popping out text boxes for you over the interface.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean, HTML page will take input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option controlling an html page. You can extract an elemet from the html page and set or get data from these elements.

[Watin](http://watin.org/)

if you are using IE then may be you can also use msthml class in .NET

Comment: Actually I dont want to embed any browser control with my window application instead opening a new instance of browser (mostly Firefox Or Chrome) it self with web site url, pass username and password and click on button to sing in.

Comment: Watin should help you raul.Using that you can open instance of browser and pass the required data to the page. check out the sample code in its home page.