# webrequest forms-authentication

Tags: c#, cookies, forms-authentication, webrequest

What I want to do is log into a website and extract data from it. I know the means to this is through a webrequest and forms-authentication but everything I've found code wise seems to be in small bits and pieces and I am having a hard time piecing together an example to work off of.

Does anyone have an example I can use or good direction for a starting point on this?

Comment: I can't think of one good example, but there are lots of posts on Web Scraping on SO that would probably be helpful.  Make sure you look at using a CookieContainer (maintain session across multiple requests) and the HTML Agility Pack if you need to parse HTML content.

Comment: Thanks Zachary, that is another problem I am running into. I know I will have to use a CookieContainer, I'll take a look at posts on web scraping and see if I can find anything to help get me started.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975426/how-to-programmatically-log-in-to-a-website-to-screenscape