# Login to website using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, authentication, web-scraping

Before everyone gets upset that this has been answered. I have scoured the web looking for how to do this and have tried a number of methods. [Login to website, via C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930807/c-sharp-login-to-website-via-program) and [How to programmatically log in to a website to screenscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975426/how-to-programmatically-log-in-to-a-website-to-screenscape) Both of these were helpful but I cannot figure out why I cannot get past the login page. Here is my code:

```
string url = "https://www.advocare.com/login.aspx";
string url2 = "https://url.after.login";
HttpWebRequest wReq = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
wReq.KeepAlive = true;
wReq.Method = "POST";
wReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
wReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string postData = "ctl00$cphContent$txtUserName=Username&ctl00$cphContent$txtPassword=Password";
byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
wReq.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
using (Stream postStream = wReq.GetRequestStream())
{
   postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse wResp = wReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
string pageSource;
wReq = WebRequest.Create(url2) as HttpWebRequest;
wReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
wReq.CookieContainer.Add(wResp.Cookies);
HttpWebResponse wResp2 = wReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp2.GetResponseStream()))
{
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Everytime I look at pageSource it is the HTML for the login.aspx page. I must be missing something here. Maybe it's not taking the cookie, I don't know. One question I have aside from, why doesn't this work, is in the string postData = "". Are those suppose to be the name or id portion of the html tag? Any help on this is greatly appreciated as I am stumped and will have to find a different way. I would like to continue with the `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` instead of using `WebBrowser`. If I can't, oh well. Thanks again for any help!

Comment: @Fastlink - well, before sendin the post data , u need to make a get request bcoz "VIEWSTATE" is sent in post data

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do besides login?  If its like QAing a site programically, i would suggest using selenium andcreate a c# app based off of that.   If u want i can post a link to a base project for a selenium based project.

Comment: Simply, I need to get to a few pages behind the login, scrape the pages, load scraped data into database so user can search database

Answer (score 0):

Don't necessarily view the page source, but look at the actual HTTP POST. Install a HTTP proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) and then re-visit the page you are trying to emulate. Complete the HTTP POST request, and check out the results produced in the proxy. From there you'll be able to see the actual parameters, cookies, headers, etc. that are being passed and you can then attempt to replicate this in your code. It's often easy to miss something when simply viewing the HTML source but monitoring the network traffic is pretty straight forward.