# Is it possible to login from a winforms application to a website which uses spring security?

Tags: java, c#, winforms, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to call a web service from my winforms application. My application is written on c# and the webservice is secured using spring security.

Is it possible to login to the website and call that web service?.

If it is possible how to do that?

Comment: Sure, do you have an existing Spring security configuration?

Comment: Yes, I have, and the web service is deployed in google app engine. The service I need call is a secured URL. So I need to login first. I tried using the solution explained here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975426/how-to-programmatically-log-in-to-a-website-to-screenscape

Comment: But I were unable to login. I have changed the field names and URL as per the spring specification. But still it was not logging in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication can be setup in many ways with Spring Security. For example:

```xml
<http pattern="/webservice/**" create-session="stateless" realm="TestRealm">
  <http-basic/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</http>
```

Then it is as simple as this to authenticate from C#:

```csharp
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd);
```